# How many ways to place identical boxes in a row?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways there are to arrange ten (or n) identical boxes in a row of ten (or n) places when stacking is allowed? I guess you need to find how many different arrays there are but how?

Comment: If you consider the height of stack $j$ as $x_j$, then you're looking at the equation
$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + \ldots + x_{10} = n
$$
The number of solutions can be found with the "stars and bars" method.

Comment: This is an example of a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was quite sure this was some classical problem but just couldn't figure it out myself

Answer (score 2):

Arrange the $n$ boxes in a row, like so:
$$\square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \ldots\  \square\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \tag{1}$$
There are $n-1$ spaces in between. "Stacking" the boxes means inserting a $|$ into some of the spaces in $(1)$, indicating when a new stack shall begin. Since there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to choose a subset of the $n-1$ spaces there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to arrange the boxes in a row of nonempty stacks.